# Offsetting Data using python-ldap Library

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, openldap, python-ldap

I am working with the python-ldap library, trying to retrieve all groups and associated data with a Lambda Function (python3.7). However, the data that is being ingested is so large the function runs out of memory before completing (max memory 3008MB). I am looking at the documentation to try and figure out how to pull the data in chunks but am having a hard time understanding how to do this. I am looking at the `SimplePagedResultsControl` option but do not understand the *cookie* parameter.  My goal is to pull say the first 30,000 records, then 30,001 to 60,000, etc. using some type of offset or data chunking strategy running multiple concurrent lambda functions. Can someone help me better understand how to do this?

Comment: Check this [post](https://medium.com/@alpolishchuk/pagination-of-ldap-search-results-with-python-ldap-845de60b90d2).

Comment: @EricLavault so in that instance, would I be able to do something like this with 3 functions? set the first ```pages=0 and while pages < 40000``` and then another function ```pages=40001 and while pages >= 40001 and pages < 80000``` . ?

Comment: Not really, but much better : you would iterate the search until no results given some paginaton controls, eg. `page_control = SimplePagedResultsControl(True, size=40000, cookie='')`. Look at the code snippet at the end of the post.